# « Je vous demande de me juger par les ennemis que je me suis faits » : accord, formulation ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, prépositions, accord, verbes-pronominaux

L'ex-patron du *FBI*, M. James Comey, a répondu aux propos d'un [troll d'Internet](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26522696) de la manière suivante sur une [plateforme de microblogage](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26502395) :

> “I ask you to judge me by the enemies I have made.” — FDR

Il s'agit d'une reformulation de [propos](http://www.fdrlibrary.marist.edu/_resources/images/msf/msf00530) (p. 29 : « My friends, judge me by the enemies I have made. ») du 32<sup>e</sup> président des États-Unis, [*Franklin D. Roosevelt*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_Delano_Roosevelt). Dans un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/201901/11/01-5210785-trump-se-dechaine-apres-des-revelations-sur-ses-liens-avec-la-russie.php), je lis une traduction :

> Je vous demande de me juger par les ennemis que je me suis *faits*. (La Presse, via l'AFP)

On semble avoir fait l'accord en nombre (*faits*) comme si on introduisait un [adjectif attribut](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3314) ; [ailleurs](http://www.lefigaro.fr/flash-actu/2019/01/12/97001-20190112FILWWW00095-affaire-russe-trump-se-dechaine-apres-des-revelations-du-new-york-times.php) non. Autre part, des robots [échouent](https://www.brainyquote.com/fr/citation/franklin-d-roosevelt_135688) lamentablement...

---

- Peut-on analyser la phrase en français et expliquer précisément par la présentation de la règle qui convient pourquoi il y a accord ou pourquoi c'est invariable ?
- Peut-on indiquer la fonction grammaticale de *par les ennemis que je
  me suis [faire]*, déterminer s'il est cohérent de l'introduire avec
  la préposition ([juger](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/juger)) [*par*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/par) ou autrement suggérer la préposition/formulation adéquate ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On pourrait tourner à la forme non pronominale ainsi :

> les ennemis que j'ai fait**s** à moi-même.

On comprend de cela que le *me* du *je me suis* est un complément d'attribution et *les ennemis* le COD.

En application stricte de la règle générale d'accord du participe passé des verbes pronominaux quand le COD précède le participe, on accordera le participe passé avec le COD, ainsi :

> *les ennemis que je me suis fait**s***

Précisément comme aurait dit Stendhal : *Suivant les maximes qu'il s'était faites, il considéra ses...*

La seconde interrogation de l'OP est en revanche très légitime au sens où *par* introduit usuellement un complément d'agent et qu'en conséquence, pris isolément, avec *juger par les ennemis*, on serait fondé à comprendre que ce sont les ennemis qui jugent alors que ce n'est évidemment pas le sens de la phrase.

Dans le sens souhaité par l'auteur, il est d'évidence que *les ennemis faits* porte un sens causal. Serait ce sur quoi le jugement se fonderait, la raison du jugement.

Dans ce cas, ce n'est effectivement pas la préposition *par* que j'aurais choisie mais bien la locution prépositive ***de*** par et, avec... un autre Président... ( *Il était, de par son caractère, fait pour agir*) j'aurais dit :

> *Je vous demande de me juger **de** par les ennemis que je me suis fait**s**.*

<sub>NDaCOSwt : Jacques Gaudin signale en commentaires l'existence d'une page bien curieuse du site internet de l'AF, page dont **l**'auteur viserait effectivement à limiter l'usage de la locution prépositive *de par*.</sub>
<sub>Je ne peux que recommander d'ignorer cette restriction pour mille et une raisons dont... non  la moindre : L'Académie Française l'ignore elle-même!</sub>
<sub>Il suffira de consulter les articles consacrés à [AUXILIAIRE](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/auxiliaire), [GOÛTEUR](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/go%C3%BBteur), [IRRESPONSABLE](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/irresponsable), [NAÎTRE](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/na%C3%AEtre), [NOBLESSE](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/noblesse) etc. dans la 9e et dernière édition du Dictionnaire pour s'en convaincre.</sub>

Comment: Très bonne réponse. Cependant l'usage de "de par" est limité à certains cas précis. http://www.academie-francaise.fr/de-par